# my reducer is executed but state does not update in react

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am using recat redux for my project and in one component I need to update my state but since I am dealing with asynchronous call I need to do the action call in  my componentDidUpdate as follows:

```
 componentDidUpdate() {
   this.props.updateHamburgerMenu(this.props.Channel.channelIdArr);
}
```

and here is my action:

```
export function updateHamburgerMenu(channelIdArr) {

return dispatch => {
    dispatch(
        {
            type: "UPDATE_HAMBURGER_MENU",
            payload:   {
                "channelIdArr":channelIdArr
            }

        }
    );

};
}
```

and in my reducer I have :

```
switch (action.type) {
case "UPDATE_HAMBURGER_MENU":

        var channelList=state.allChannelList.slice();

        channelList.unshift({
            "id": channelIdArr[0],
            "channelName": "sssssssss",
            "status": "Inactive"
        });
        alert("reducer called");
        state.allChannelList=channelList;

        break;}
        return state;
```

Now when I run it I can see that the alert is working but state does not update at all.

Also I tried another way as follow:

```
 state={"channelsArr":state.channelsArr,"AllChannels":state.AllChannels,"channelIdArr":state.channelIdArr,"channelLabelForScrolls":[], "latestAction":action.type, "allChannelList":channelList};
        break;
```

This way, it seems that state keep updating and it goes in infinite loop. 
It is really confusing, can anyone help? what am I missing?

Update:

When I separate the allChannelList in another reducer it works. So it seems that updating allChannelList  in a specific case of componentdidupdate goes to infinite loop and state keep updating itself. BUt I have no idea why it is happenning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your reducer case statements, you should be returning a new object which represents the state after the current action - you appear to be trying to assign directly to the `allChannelList` property on the passed in `state` object.

i.e.

```
return {
    ...state,
    allChannelList: channelList
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer actually I did not put the return state here but in my actual code I return the state I updated the code snippet. I return state as follow: return state. is that right?

Comment: Also I tried this now:    state={
        ...state,
            allChannelList: channelList
        } and it goes to infinite execution and keep updating state

Comment: You don't want to do anything to the passed in `state` object; you just need to return a complete new object like in my example above

Comment: I did exactly what you said but it what I see is just contentious alert("reducer called"); that I intentionally put there for test and never  which means that state keeps  updating !!!!

Comment: I'm guessing because you are dispatching your action from `componentDidUpdate`, it will be updating after each time and calling it again.

Comment: I checked the componentDidUpdate it is executed just once but strangely in reducer it keeps updating. Should I create a new reducer and have separate reducer for this case. Is it a good practice?

Comment: Also, you don't need to `break` in your case statements since you are returning from them

Comment: I removed the break no result

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149950/discussion-between-tony-and-hamed-minaee).

Comment: May I see your complete reducer please.